# Rails Last_enable Devise check User Online

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using a gem for devise called Last_enable https://github.com/ctide/devise_lastseenable and I would like to implement an if statement on my user view , to display a logo "Online" if this statement is true .

My user controller :

```
 def online
    online = User.where('last_seen > ?', 5.minutes.ago)
  end
```

the 'online' query works in console and return a user. I just dont really know how to implement that on my view, or do a check if this statement is valid :

```
 <% if #What should I write here to check if my user is online ? %>
   <%= image-tag('assets/true.png') %>
 <% else %>
   <%= image-tag('assets/point_red.png') %>
 <% end %>
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I just put that `@online` I missed the `@` and it worked